# Half of half by chance

Tags: probability, expected-value

We are given $2^n$ numbers: $1,2,...,2^n$ ($n$ is integer). Then repeat $n$ times the following process: split those numbers in half and flip a coin with $p$ probability for heads. If the result for a half is tails we ignore that certain half otherwise we proceed. For example: if $n=2$ then we have the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$. We flip the coin $2$ times and let's suppose the result is $T$, $H$. So now we are dealing with $3$, $4$. We flip again the coin $2$ times so if the result is $H$, $T$ then only $3$ remains. How many numbers remain in average in this experiment?

I have calculated that in average $2^n p^n$ numbers remain. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

**I think your answer is correct.**

The number of integers remaining is 0 if at least one of the flips is TT, and it is $2^i$ if exactly $i$ flips are HH, and remaining are TH or HT. Thus, the average number of integers remaining is $(2p)^n$.